# How to setup multiple async methods into a queue?

Tags: c#, .net, queue, async-await, .net-4.5

I just picked up async/await, and I wrote a series of async methods that each perform a database SQL task and tied each one to a different button.  The GUI doesn't get locked when you click a button, so I figure that's awesome.

However, if you click each one the desired result would be the second button would wait for the first task to finish, and so on.  However, with async/await if I click multiple buttons I'm not guaranteed which will finish first.  So it can create some unwanted race conditions that cause the SQL queries to fail.

Is there a class/object/keyword or something that I can use to instead of having each async method handle an individual SQL command it instead adds it to a queue and somehow the queue is processed serially only when something has been added to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many possible designs for this. But I always prefer TPL Dataflow.

You can use an `ActionBlock` and post `async` delegates into it to be processed sequentially:

```
ActionBlock<Func<Task>> _block = new ActionBlock<Func<Task>>(action => action());

block.Post(async () => 
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    MessageBox.Show("bar");
});
```

Another possible solution would be to asynchronously wait on a `SemphoreSlim` set to 1 before executing your `async` operation so you ensure only a single one can be executed at a time:

```
SemaphoreSlim _semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1);

_semaphore.WaitAsync()
try
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    MessageBox.Show("bar");
}
finally
{
    _semaphore.Release();
}
```

Comment: Great examples, thanks.  I figured there was something easy like this, just hard to search for if you don't know the name of it.

Comment: is there a way to see how many tasks are in the queue at any given point?

Comment: @user17753 block. InputQueue

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand the problem but what you can do if you want to wait for specific tasks to finish before you do something else is put the tasks you start in local variable or a list ant use Wait on your task or Task.WaitAll so at this point the code waits for the tasks to compete. If you give more details maybe we can provide a better solution.